Should you refactor when there are no tests?
I collaborate on a mature app. It's quite messy since no code review has been practiced for decades. It's hard to maintain. It's clear for me that at some point, it will become so unmaintainable that the project will collapse under its own weight. As it's the company's key product, it is likely to go south as well
I want to be a professional. Professionals care. So it's no wonder I can't help refactoring whenever I introduce some feature or fix a bug
But here's a problem: we got no tests. And we won't have them in the foreseeable future (if at all). There are a number of reasons for that:

We don't have a spec. It's not always clear what we should assert in our tests
The codebase is huge, it will take years to provide any decent test coverage. It's negligible now
Neither managers nor the tech lead would be happy to see us spending a lot of time writing unit tests. They care about the backlog which they see as an unrelated problem (I wasn't convincing yet)
It's frontend, GUI is tricky to test

So it's a minefield. Any changes, including refactoring, risk breaking something. It may come up months later. It may be some trivial thing, it may be mission-critical
In the end, it's either a slow death (it becomes unmaintainable) or a death by a thousand cuts (too many bugs). It seems these are the only ways the project can evolve now
But what should I do as a professional developer under these circumstances?

Refactor and risk my income, my professional reputation, but feel somewhat better (I'm doing the right thing)
Not refactor and see the quality of code degrade with each passing day. I will likely solve more tasks, break fewer things, earn more money (they pay more if you solve more tasks) but feel I sacrificed professional integrity in the process (and part of my identity)


What stage of your career are you in?

@PlayerOne I'll have one year of experience this fall. I wish I started my developer career earlier, but I had challenges

Look into approval testing. It's a way around "don't dare refactor because we have no tests" dilemma. Here's a C++ link but they are available for many languages. https://approvaltestscpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ This won't solve your problem, but it changes the task from "build several thousand unit tests" to "get approval tests working" which is a much smaller hurdle.

This question is similar to: How can I convince the tech lead to improve our coding standards?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

“We don't have a spec.” — I'd say that you do have a spec: the existing app itself.  It may not be written down, but it's probably easier to write tests for — just ensure that the current codebase passes, and you can't go far wrong.  (Even if it has bugs, they may be bugs that people are used to and don't necessarily want fixed.)

You say the tech lead doesn't want to see you spend time writing a lot of unit tests. What about a little? Is there no time and buy in to write tests at all or just not for everything that already exists?

@keshlam of course, it's different. This question is not about convincing anyone about standards generally, it's about what I should do personally when it comes to enforcing one specific standard, code quality (a.k.a. refactoring) in the absence of tests

I’m voting to close this question because it better fits to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Since comments are transient, I have folded my most recent comment back into the answer.

@SophieSwett: Sorry, but it doesn't work that way. Anytime you touch code, you are assuming responsibility for any change in its behavior. Refactoring involves touching a censored large amount of code. Unless it is being done with managements blessing,, it is a great opportunity to look like a villain. As in the law, "I didn't know" maybe an explanation, but is not an excuse. You break it, you bought it, you fix it.

@keshlam I should have been clearer and mentioned that what I was saying only applies if you do have the higher-ups' blessing to do some refactoring. I definitely agree that if you "go rogue" and refactor stuff against managers' wishes, and something goes wrong, then that's on you.

@SophieSwett: I'd still say that writing tests, if necessary, to prove that you're refactored code does the same thing the old code did is part of the refactoring job. If you don't do it, and the customer find something breaks, you will be asked why you didn't do it. "There weren't tests before" will not be considered an adequate answer.

@Helena The question asks about the specific issue of refactoring, but the answers seem to be applicable to non-software related cases, such as an aircraft engineer asking how to improve their company's seemingly neglected quality assurance processes.

I vote to reopen as this question is, in the end, about professionalism, not software engineering. Added the tag

Moved my comment into my answer.

I agree that the question could be edited to be about professionalism. However, I honestly think you have gotten the best answers you are going to get for your situation as you've described it. If you have a question about professionalism more generally which has not already been answered, you could start a new Question for that.

Changing the codebase in a way in which the owners don't approve of is not ok and should not make you feel better. Whatever coding standards you believe the codebase is not adhering to is irrelevant until you either get the authority to make a change or convince the people who do have it to make a change.

@NeilMeyer another way of looking at it is the owners are in charge of what, I am in charge of how. If the owners are not happy with my performance (believe me, it's very good – actually I'm the best on the team, if we consider the number of solved tasks, by a big margin), they can start looking for another dev. Considering the pay and the stack, they are going to face a big challenge with that

The world appreciates your "Piss and Vinegar". The next generation (you) are the future. The previous generations (us) are not stupid. Even those of us that learned on punchcards. Some of us acted like you are acting now, and were smacked down for it - in much less polite times.
Please try to understand, most of the responses are about you telling a company how to run their business. Of course, refactoring and testing are great.
You can't do everything at once. It is wrong, demeaning, disrespectful to assume that you know better than everyone.
The company is making a living. The product is being maintained.
Is there tech debt - Heck yes.
So, first question - What is the purpose of the company? Hint, it isn't the product. It is to make money. You may think the product is for crap, but it must be serving the needs of the paying customers.
Second question - Do you know what the company's long term strategy is? Are you on the board? Do they have plan for a rewrite in the future? That is information that they would keep close to the vest.
Incremental improvements - can you add unit tests for your work without being overly disruptive? That would be helpful.
By the way - A delivered product beats the heck out of a perfect product. (Yes - it should be a working and tested product.)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The world is full of terribly written code that serves it's purpose and does a job. As a person who only recently had to deal with legacy code for the first time. I had to let go my starry-eyed notions of good coding practices for the ideals of if it ain't broke don't fix and keep it simple stupid.

To address the specific point: in the absence of tests, write tests. In the absence of a spec, write a spec too. Yes, this means that the already huge task of refactoring has just tripled in size. This is undoubtedly part of why you are being told that it is too expensive to tackle wholesale at this time. So what you should do is accept that, set the idea aside, and do your assigned job. In a few years, if you still feel this is critical, you can try proposing it again. For now, they heard you, they disagree, and if you want to continue being paid you will accept that.
Being a professional means caring about the things that matter to the company even if you disagree. Being a professional means doing your best work even when you don't feel like it. By all means voice your opinions. Then accept management's decision. If they disagree with you, let It go and move on. If you can't, you can try moving on to another job... but you will probably still have to learn the same lesson. If you insist on doing it your way, without a lot more experience to back up your opinions, you had better start your own company because you are going to be unemployable.
Refactoring isn't just expensive. It risks introducing new bugs, and takes effort away from chasing current bugs or developing new function. It is rarely a good investment unless you need to expose internal interfaces which are currently not well-defined. Code cleanup is usually best done incrementally, as a side effect of more urgent work.
Your project lead, after consulting the team and considering cost, benefits, and risk, sets priorities. Provide input, by all means, but then work to those priorities.
Or move to academia, where elegance is more important and practicality less so.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Dealing with legacy code bases is special
Do you have a background in academics? Former student? Youngbloods often have the notion of "hey, this is not according to standards. Where are the standards I learned from the books?".
You are in the special situation of dealing with a legacy code "blob". And no book has ever told you that they exist. They are a "socio-economical system" (aka historically grown) entangled several layers deep and a pure mess of code. Everything you should not do is in there. And you need to make sure not to lose your sanity on it. That is already tough enough.
The thing you need to do is: Separate the concern you would have with your software from that you have as an employee to the company's software. You do not "own" the software. It was "owned" before. Ignore the quality standards you have towards all legacy code. That is just "there".
As you mentioned, the project is huge and evolved over long times. You cannot undo the damage that is already there. All your refactoring efforts will just cost you time and energy and bring you nothing. The "good feeling" is none, because you are working on old and aged code. All the work will be frustrating and stressful and make you need to explain why you are "so slow".
Do not touch it unless you have to during a project/sprint. You do not know what dependencies there are lurking and if a refactoring would break it. After changing something QA or Helpdesk will have increasing cases of failure reports and the question will rise "Who touched that part... we were not working on that part...". You need the cover of a project or sprint to "allow producing" bugs, because only then you have the time and the obligation to care for them.
The only thing you can do is trying to make it better on those parts you are writing new or have to improve by project/sprint demands. Here you can uphold your standards. Estimate times to include writing tests. Do not tell anyone, just assume they are normal and mandatory for your work and go without saying. You are a professional after all.
You are also anticipating the future without knowing what will happen (if the code is 20 years old, the company did something right / not clean code tho). Don't try to predict. Go with it (for a little while) and see how it turns out. You need proof not suspicion. Closely observe if you are satisfied working there. If you cannot handle legacy systems, try looking for a new job. It is not for everyone. Watch out not to burn out on it.

Thank you. One more thing to note. When your customers and users are different people, user satisfaction is not as strongly linked to the company's success. That's why we could get away with more mess. I'm not sure it's a common case

The company's customer is the users.Your customer is the company.  Unless you can present actual business numbers showing the company that an investment in change will produce more income, they are not likely to make a large investment in change. "The customer is not always right. The customer is always the one holding the money. Would you rather be right, or paid?"

And after only a year in the industry, you really do not have the perspective to justify your claim that you are right. You are overly focused on one thing you would like to fix. There are undoubtedly lots of other things that need fixing and that will make you look better, faster. Work those. If you are still with the company in 5 years, you may have some standing to argue for major breaking changes. Or by then, the company may have decided to rewrite the thing from scratch or discontinue it entirely.

@SergeyZolotarev: For some context; at my last job, we had a codebase that was pretty hefty, but was still maintained, and it was directly related to helping another team ship a rather major product on a yearly basis. One of my teammates at the same experience level as me did decry the codebase structure and claimed we needed to refactor it, but...it was 100+ files large at this point, and it was more important that we were able to support the other team than for our code to be "POSIX compliant", given our code ran on Windows machines, and deadlines were a factor.

@SergeyZolotarev: We did make improvements to our codebase and cleaned up technical debt, and sometimes re-wrote things - but all of that only happened in a brief weeks-long window between when we shipped one version of the product and then had to wait for the other team to get progress ramped up on their other code base and need our support again. Which ultimately meant that we would be triaging what specific things to fix, or to add. We had a testing suite, as I understand, but it was very generic, and meant to work with new files without us adding more tests.

@keshlam: "The company's customer is the users" - no; the company's customer is whoever's buying the software. Sometimes that will be the users directly, but often software is bought by one group of people to be used by another group. This can often result in the software sucking from the point of view of the users, because they're not the ones calling the shots - but of course the company is still right to prioritise whoever's paying the bills!

Regarding books, there are some about working with legacy code, including a 20 years old book by Michael Feathers which seems to be quite popular.

@psmears: Granted. Usually the two interests of those groups are somewhat aligned. Nonetheless, the point is that whether you agree with the company's direction or not, once you have expressed your disagreement, you should accept their decision and continue to do what they ask you to do to the best of your ability. If you failed to make your case, either you were wrong, or your timing was wrong, or you don't understand your case well enough to make it in business terms; in any of these cases, set it aside and come back to it in a few years.

You are making some pretty big claims here

It's clear for me that at some point, it will become so unmaintainable that the project will collapse under its own weight. As it's the company's key product, it is likely to go south as well

You may be right, you may be wrong. But it's clear that your leadership doesn't agree with you:

Neither managers nor the tech lead would be happy to see us spending a lot of time writing unit tests.

If you truly believe the claims you're making in your lead paragraph, it's up to you to convince leadership that you're right and they are in fact risking the company's future.
Do stop to consider at some point if you might be wrong; I've heard the claim that "this product is unmaintainable" many, many times in my career and it's never actually turned out to be true. Devs love to refactor things, but it's honestly a rare dev who is able to correctly trade off the cost of refactoring against the lost opportunity cost of developing new features.

Thank you. Though, you haven't seen what I have. It's actually that bad. The worst things you can possibly imagine. It will make your hair stand on end. That's how bad it is

With all due respect, with a year of experience you don't have the knowledge to judge that.

I don't claim to have a lot of experience, but I do claim to have sufficient knowledge to tell the good from the bad. I learned from the best who do have both knowledge and experience (even more than you do)

@SergeyZolotarev In software development it is rarely the case that there are objectively right or wrong things. There are only trade offs. Until you understand why things were done a certain way (was it because the writer didn't know there was a better way, or they did know a different way but intentionally chose what they did for a specific reason) you could just end up making things worse. In many cases, a refactor or rewrite will just end up being a sideways move, with different, unforeseen, problems caused by making a different choice in a given trade off.

I will repeat: do stop to consider at some point if you might be wrong.

@WillemRenzema no, it's actually much simpler. First, if no one sees what you do, you're more likely to do wrong (unapproved of) things. It works in areas beside software development (e.g. less exposed urban areas tend to be more littered). Second, the language, Java, lacked many crucial features when the project was born (e.g. generics) so they couldn't be used. The same goes for frameworks that we now take for granted (testing frameworks, modern ORM, DI). Third, if there are few standards at the company level (no spec, no QA), rank-and-file employees are also more likely to slack

@WillemRenzema fourth, prior devs, indeed, simply may not have known better (lacked expertise and made wrong design decisions)

@PhilipKendall About what, exactly?

Everyone coming to look at a new codebase always thinks it's lousy and can be improved.  (The last bit, at least, is always right.)  Thinking that it's unmaintainable and would be better junked and rewritten from scratch is also very common — but IME evolution is almost always better than revolution.

@SergeyZolotarev the assumption that your way would be better.

When you try to reverse engineer legacy systems is often a very self-soothing trap to fall in to think everybody who worked on it where incompetent. In my experience it is more likely that it is not that there were no patterns, it is more likely you don't have the skills to recognise the patterns. After all software being rushed to market and being patched into working order is as old as the profession itself.


what should I do as a professional developer under these circumstances?

If you're breaking more things, doing less tasks & making less money due to personal preferences, this is not at all professional. Don't conflate professionalism with how you 'feel', or equate professional integrity with whatever it is you have. They're clearly not the same thing.

Right, I used to tell my students, "programmers are not paid to have opinions."

@HappyIdiot Software engineers are though. The jobs where no opinion is required are being moved to India and Co. in many companies...

@AlexGeorg my point was that correct approaches should not be a matter of "personal preference" (opinion).

@HappyIdiot correct approaches only matter to a business when it effects the bottom line. Some programmers think there opinions matter but the only opinion that matters is the one that effects the bottom line. You are not going to find a sympathetic manager when you want to tell him the software that is working and paying everybody's salaries is bad and needs to be rewritten.



I want to be a professional.
Professionals care.
refactoring whenever I introduce some feature or fix a bug
But here's a problem: we got no tests


The other answers seem to focus mostly on 1 => 2 or 2 => 3 eg the position/responsibilities of an engineer in a company, what's practical, ownership, relationship between good code and product success.
This is probably the more important part of the question and something most engineers iterate on throughout their careers. However I'd like to focus on the interaction between 3 & 4.
As you've stated, that's where the contradiction arises: you want to improve the codebase (through refactoring) but there are no tests and even worse, the domain and the way the codebase is structured makes it hard to test: "it's a minefield".
It doesn't matter why or how this happened: this is the state of it. Given this state, a lot of principles about how a professional developer should code do not apply.
Does this mean that it's a free for all? No! It just means a different set principles apply, suited for this state. It's not dissimilar to being a personal trainer: you don't recommend the same exercise routine to a beginner, a seasoned athlete, someone in their 80s etc.
Finding what principles should guide your development, given the state of the codebase, product, language, tooling, deployment procedures etc is part of the responsibilities of a professional developer. Working Effectively with Legacy Code might be an interesting read, although again, one should evaluate how to apply principles instead of just following generic advice.

Thank you. Do you have practical advice?

You may check what you can achieve with generous assertions instead of unit tests. Less work. Can be added easily. Doesn’t require explicitly adding unit tests. A bit more chaotic.
Where it is weaker is that you cannot create systematic tests but only test what happens to be used.
It also works well if there is no specification. You try to figure out the specification then add assertions for it. If your guess was wrong you fix the assertion.

Right, an Assertion is like a circuit breaker: the house won't burn down, but the lights will go off. Similarly, be sparing with data absolutes (SQL Constraints) but definitely use them where necessary.

Used properly, assertions can be very valuable.  In a situation like the OP's, however, one needs to be very aware that "used properly" includes disabling assertions in release builds, because they can easily change "it works for the wrong reason" or "it works well enough" or similar to "it crashes hard".  And of course, if one is going to add assertions to a big legacy project then one needs to watch out for assertions having been improperly used somewhere in the code.

@JohnBollinger I like having three build targets: release, debug (with debugging code), and release + asserts. The last is run on a development machine from time to time to find bugs that are hidden by a debug build.

The correct way to add assertions to an unfamiliar project is in a non-destructive way. Don't code something as if a != b, return until you are absolutely positive that a and b MUST always be the same. Code it instead as if a != b, log("a != b", a, b) and don't return. You don't know this code. When you get logs you have to investigate why a isn't b, and what to do: 1) handle a != b as a premature return with or without error, especially if you see it a lot; 2) fix a small number of places that pass bad a or bad b; or 3) make the function handle a != b in some sensible manner.


As it's the company's key product, it is likely to go south as well

Provided the existing edifice is complicated (therefore providing some barrier to entry by any other software company, or transition costs for users), and there is an existing version of the software that continues to work well (or work well enough in critical areas), then the collapse of a company with unmaintainable legacy code will often be gradual at first, because they can continue to use or retail what they already have, even if they don't really understand the workings of the application anymore and cannot change them.
There's also often a similar firm in the market filling a similar niche, so the next stage of dealing with unmaintainable code could be to gradually transfer trade to the firm that has the better working software, or explicitly buy one firm out and consolidate the two operations and the commercial relationships. Not every solution revolves around developers fixing that legacy code, or even involves the management of the failed firm keeping their jobs.
You've explained in comments that you have only a year's experience.
In general that means you should be at a stage in life where you are either writing modest and lower-stakes greenfield projects so as to self-learn the basics of the trade from practical activity, which you will then grow further over time, or you should be working and studying under much more experienced staff who wrote an existing codebase and are in a position to explain the complicated features and concepts of the business operation which the application solves, so that when the next rewrite occurs you can keep up and contribute to the design, and following that rewrite you are then an experienced practitioner who knows how to maintain that application, or you can go on to write new complicated (rather than simple) greenfield applications.
The natural order of things is that developers create and then oversee the code of their application until its death - that is, until it is completely replaced again, whether replaced by a fresh design of their own making, or by a fresh design by new generation of staff (who have hopefully been trained by the old, but often haven't).
There are very few software applications out there with code older than a single career-span, and few applications manage to sustain a total turnover of development staff with no continuity between the staff.
Unfortunately we live in a world where management in this area has become so poor that inexperienced developers often do end up being sat down in front of a computer, and expected to maintain and readapt extremely complicated legacy applications.
It's akin to a massive corporation having systems and written procedures spread across all its business functions that took many staff years or decades to learn, create, and refine, and then giving it all to a fresh university graduate to oversee and alter without any real supervision or initiation.
The common refrain is that the developer then says it has to be redone because it's a mess and they don't understand it, which by then it probably is, and they don't and never will.
What young developers don't have is the perspective to understand how absurdly their own management is behaving in putting them in that position, and they often don't have the bargaining power to seek a better job.

But what should I do as a professional developer under these circumstances?

If you can, leave and find something better, where you either have access to more experienced staff who will explain things, or where you will be left to get on with greenfield development.
The only places where legacy applications are written to such a standard that they would be worth studying like archaeology, tend to be those that wouldn't just let an inexperienced developer loose and expect him to muddle through. The benefit of being around these legacy applications and staff would be obvious, because I've seen and used such ancient applications in my own career and they shine bright with subtlety, structure, and order.
Most legacy applications however are just the failed results of some other inexperienced developer's greenfield development a few years earlier, who the employing firm has already chewed up and spat out, and these applications contain nothing interesting or profound to study, only inexperience, foolishness, and absurdity. I've seen a few of these over the years, too.
So my advice would be to vote with your feet.
I wouldn't bother tying to massively alter the firm's development style. You won't have enough experience yet to prescribe effective changes (rather than things that just increase inefficiency or go down a blind alley), you won't have much clout anyway because of your limited experience, and often managers are hiring inexperienced developers as fresh meat because they don't want to hear what those who already have clout would say.

Thank you. But I'm going to stick around for a while so I'll have to make choices

@SergeyZolotarev, for the reasons I say in this long answer, there won't necessarily be any choice you can make which reconciles your desired professionalism with your continued employment in this particular role. So if you've made the decision to stay, and you can stay, then you've also made the decision to set a low standard. Some software companies make good profits retailing buggy crap, and some developers write that buggy crap, that's the truth.

This answer has great points about greenfield projects for less experienced people and the more experienced people explaining the existing code, which is hopefully good enough to be worth learning from. In the Apprenticeship scenario, newbies get basic tasks to develop skills, journeymen get projects to gain responsibility, and 'masters' (of the craft) manage, direct things overall, and show how the subtle stuff is done. This is somewhat true in software (because it works) but not really endorsed anywhere now, sadly.

@HappyIdiot, it's because the large corporations and governmental departments have either collapsed and been balkanised, or they've become parasitic on consuming pre-made foreign labour, so the contexts and impetus for apprenticeships in the Western world were largely destroyed about 30 years ago. (1/2)

With only smaller firms who have only one or two developers, who are all competing amongst themselves to slash costs, attack wages, and poach workforces, and with only amateur management, there is neither the perspective, the economic feasibility, nor the workplace context for operating an apprentice scheme to formally reproduce professional knowledge anymore. It's not just business administration and information systems in which skills have collapsed. Everything from bricklaying to lawyering has. (2/2)

Right, and the continuing advice (even from someone I knew decades ago) that the only ways to get competitive pay are job hopping and owning the company, undermine longevity at a company. Someone commented that staying in one place 13 years was foolish. So there we are.

@HappyIdiot, those remarks could have come from my very own mouth! That unfortunately has been the only way to get competitive pay in the circumstances of recent decades. The old days of pay scales, collective bargaining, and final salary pensions are gone.

I disagree with several points. "Vote with your feet" is often going to lead to finding that "the grass is always greener on the other side of the fence". It isn't, it's the same colour.
I think there are lots of applications older than one career. Most are in infrastructure where things are largely static. Ask a big bank how old their COBOL apps are - they were originally written in the 60s.
The PBX I worked on was written in the early 70s and probably still runs a high percentage of the business lines in Canada. 2 million lines of source with no unit test ability. But your phones work.

The trick with monolithic code is to focus your attention on the weak spots. I was our senior quality expert for 15 years. By digging into the weak points I was able to dramatically improve quality. Sergey needs to do the same. Get some experience, monitor bug reports, look for places that break repetitively, and add tests there. If they are bad enough show the data to a team lead and get permission to refactor, if there is value in doing it.

Do a balance. Always refactor only the part you are working at the moment, and also write also tests in that. That will result that you work more on a task as usual.
The likely outcome will be a stretch with the leads or management. They will think, you are doing things they did not want. They will also know, that these are needed, and actually saying it would mean that they are unprofessional! So, they wont say that. You will just feel, this is what they think. But your work, until a point, will be accepted - at a point. Try to "dance on the border" - where you are yet tolerated, but you already can make things better.
Do not have illusions. In my experience, after seeing a lot of similar, while you still do the only best possible, you are too little to change the whole system.
You will expand the lifetime of the project, but not too much. Then it will die. Likely you wont be there already at the time.

Whenever you have to fix a bug or add a feature, write tests to cover your changes.
Rationale

This is good practice for any change. Untested changes are bad irrespective of the absence of tests for other parts of the code.
This will help to do your task at hand (fixing bug, providing feature) in higher quality.
You will be able to refactor the code that is covered by your newly written tests.
Over time code coverage will increase. Encourage peers to follow this pattern. Involve your teach lead, too.


Thank you. But I need to refactor to make the classes testable in the first place

@SergeyZolotarev if you can't write functional acceptance/regression tests, you don't understand the code well enough to consider refactoring it.

@keshlam you don't get it. If dependencies are not exposed, you can't mock them (if we don't consider static mocking). As a result, you can's unit test the class. If you refer to more heavy-weight tests, I don't think rank-and-file devs should do that (it seems Bob Martin agrees with it in his book, which I trust)

@SergeyZolotarev Mocking is not the only way to write tests; it's a relatively recent tool. And beware of taking books as absolute authorities; you can always find other books that will disagree. And go back to my answer; the fact that this task is snowballing is why you are being told not to do it right now.

@keshlam if you don't address a problem and let it keep getting worse, "not right now" actually means "never"

@SergeyZolotarev: with all due respect, you are too young and inexperienced to be making claims about "forever". And this still may not be the right problem to be solving. Making the code cleaner doesn't help if folks aren't buying it because it doesn't do what they need.

@keshlam but why isn't it doing what they need? Hint: it's not because we refactor too much

No package ever does everything that the customers need. Wholesale refactoring is rarely the fastest way to get closer to the customer's need.  https://xkcd.com/1205/ is on a different issue but the trade-off remains valid.

If new things appear with higher priority,that's okay.  Things can sit on a backlog for years, or never get done at all, and that is a correct outcome. Maybe a disappointing one if you are highly attached to one particular idea, but that's you, not the business. And saying that you are not late because of refactoring does not mean that directing effort into refactoring will not make you later.

You keep trying to make an all or nothing case for massive refactoring right now. It doesn't have to be right now, it doesn't have to be massive, and like everything else that is done to the code it has to be given a priority, and worked in that priority order. Yes that may mean things come ahead of it. Yes it may mean that things continue to come ahead of it. But if they do, that is the system working correctly. Drop your monomania on refactoring and accept that other stuff has higher importance and/or urgency, and therefore higher priority, and you should be working things in priority order.

@SergeyZolotarev "never" is often the right time to refactor old code. You can't refactor just because you feel like it or think you should. Refactoring MUST be reserved for areas that are frequently changed and/or frequently broken. Change for the sake of "quality" when there is no quality problem is a fool's errand as you are likely to break things. Wait until you have seen enough problems to know what areas are weak, then consider tests and refactoring if you have to work in that code. And not before.

First thing to do is write some tests.
Having some tests (even if they are rudimentary and only cover a fraction of the functionality) is better than having no tests.  Clearly there are some behaviors that you can safely assume are desired (or undesirable) and test for, otherwise nobody would ever submit any bug reports because nobody would know what is a bug and what is a feature :).
If (okay, when) you reach the point where you are not sure whether a behavior is expected or not, writing a test to detect and report that behavior is a good way to discuss/discover/document how your users (and/or development team) actually expect the system to behave in that circumstance.  Once you've decided on that, it's then a simple matter to update the test to designate the results as pass/fail appropriately.
It's okay for the testing suite to be inadequate, since you can keep adding more tests over time until (some glorious day in the far future) you approach adequacy.  In the meantime, with every new test you add, it becomes that much less scary to refactor because the likelihood of any fresh regressions being pointed out to you by the next test-suite-run increases, and therefore the likelihood of regressions slipping through to affect users decreases.

I would assume that where the OP says "there are no tests" he really means that there are no automated unit tests like he was taught in college. I would also assume that the company does UAT of some sort, in which case switching strategy would be hugely expensive, and fairly pointless if it is done piecemeal.

"Write some tests", is far too vague as guidance for this keen new designer. The advice needs to be "determine a part of the code that is frequently subject to breakage, and write some tests for it". I worked in a 40 year old code base of over 2 million LOC with no test ability and the important thing was to focus on areas that were frequently having problems. Until you have detected patterns of failure there is not much point in randomly starting to write tests. The tests need to add value, not just be tests for the sake of tests/coverage.

Do pay attention to the stored data and how it is defined. Realistically, code can be replaced any old time or way, but data is the actual thing. Without data, all the code in the world is tinsel with no tannenbaum.
If the data is structured poorly, your code will need contortions to work with it and function properly. Data science is eclipsing coding in importance. AI can help with coding tasks but as best I know, it doesn't have expertise to condense a book of requirements into some files of SQL definitions designed to weather decades of future change and addition.
Champion the data and let everyone else ponder code conundrums . You'll be all alone, way out in front.

This answer presents a very narrow understanding of what sort of software a professional developer might work on. Data is not always the main focus but rather a part of the general equation, and I feel like the value brought on by data scientists is not as much as you think.
