How do I influence a hiring decision in a way that increases the likelihood of my new engineering colleague being product-oriented?
I’ve had the misfortune of an engineering colleague on my team (the most senior one) being not product oriented. Despite it being a startup and a small team that hasn’t yet achieved profitability, he as much as possible tried to get the team to just change internal processes as he saw fit and attain technical purity as he saw fit.
There are no dedicated engineering managers and the CEO is in charge. The engineer is now leaving the team, and I’m personally not directly involved in the hiring process for his replacement. How do I influence the team in a way that hopefully picks a new hire that’s product-oriented?

I would assume that is already their goal. Maybe if they wind up with somebody who doesn't have the proper perspective they'll fire more quickly this time. I don't see any way you can productively influence this.

Note that in some ways this is the other side of https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/198982/should-you-refactor-when-there-are-no-tests/

If you're not personally involved, how would you influence it? The only thing you can do is directly tell someone who is involved how you feel about it and hope that they care.

More directly: what is your responsibility in the company and in the team, and why is it important to you how another colleague behaves (as long as he does not attack you)? Without this information, nobody can answer. The way you asked, the answer is: "You should not even try to influence, because it is not your job" - and that is most likely not what you are looking for. So please EDIT the question and add the relevant information.

I have the experience where the product is at the risk to stop existing exactly because there are no real usable processes. If your company is like that, then you really want more people process oriented at the beginning. Once you create an unmaintainable mess (there are countless discussions on the net how to throw away such products, and redesign them from scratch), a good process will no longer help.

Does "engineer" mean "programmer" here? Or are you building physical structures? What does "product oriented" mean? That sounds like a buzzword, but its meaning isn't obvious to me. Do you mean someone who is focused on building and improving the product as opposed to someone who is focusing on internal processes?

@terdon software engineering, and correct on the last part.

It might help if you clarify then since not everyone works in the same field or recognizes the same buzzwords. I still don't quite understand what you mean by not product oriented and how that created problems and what those problems were. As a newly minted C-level in a youngish not-quite-startup-any-more doing software as a service, I can assure you that having good processes from the beginning is a huge advantage and not necessarily a bad thing at all.

If you don't know/aren't in the field you probably shouldn't answer the question.

@mxyzplk I'm very much in the field, I am just not in the US so not familiar with this sort of buzzword jargon. Not everyone uses corporate speak.

What you can do is:

Talk to those involved in the process.  "Hey, as an engineer on the team I have some thoughts on what we should be looking for."
Even better, have a suggestion on how to look for that. They probably already know from the previous guy going that he was not biased towards shipping and they need someone that is; that doesn't mean they know how to ask an engineer a meaningful question in an interview that might reveal that. For example, "tell me about a time that you were under pressure to balance a release's quality against a ship date, how you handled that and what the results were."
Even even better, suggest you can help in the interviewing, and maybe you become the missing engineering manager one day.


I think this is a good answer. Maybe expand point 2 to include explaining to the people interviewing what is meant by "product-oriented". They might be just as clueless as I am.

"product-oriented", to me, a software engineer, means that the person puts the quality of the product before other things like arbitary deadlines from sales people. When I google it, that seems to be the consensus what it means.
From your usage of the word, I take that you mean it the exact opposite way, that you want them to sacrifice product quality for earlier shipping. I think this is called market oriented and is the opposite of product oriented.
Maybe start by communicating more clearly what you mean. Explain it to the people who interview, what you are looking for. Do not use buzzwords, especially not if they are ambiguous, or in this case, maybe not even used correctly. Use full sentences, express goals and processes.
If you want them to take shortcuts to enable early shipping, say so. If you want them to keep to established processes or getting buy in from the other developers on new ones, say so. Communicate clearly.

I disagree that "product oriented" means "sacrifice quality".  I worked with a team that sounds a lot like the problem engineer the OP mentioned.  They spent long discussions on Scrum process debating the various roles and procedures, but didn't spend time on the UI, which was completely opaque.  "Product oriented" means that everything, including software processes, is subservient to shipping a good, solid product.  Focusing on process for the sake of process is counterproductive.

@DaveG Having smooth and effective software processes is a part of "shipping a good, solid product". I assume what you mean by "software processes" includes engineering details like how version control and CI/CD is set up, what kind of testing flows are set up, what code standards are followed throughout the codebase, how are environment variables processed, etc. All of those things determine your product's quality because if you are lacking in them, e.g., in testing, then your product is likelier to be subpar and further regress as time goes on. I completely agree with nvoigt here. [1/2]

@DaveG Product quality is not solely limited to how attractive the interface is, or how many functions the software does compared to its competitors. Good "engineering" is part of making a good, maintainable product. [2/2]

I will, however, say, that "market oriented a̶n̶d̶ is the opposite of product oriented." is quite debatable.

@SyedM.Sannan Clearly both engineering and product functionality go into product quality.  Of course it's important to have good, maintainable designs.  But I've seen developers who seemed solely concerned with software theory w/o caring about whether the end product is actually useful / saleable, and it sounds like that's what the OP is talking about.

@DaveG Well, I partially agree with you there. Product usability is something an engineer must not compromise on and must prioritize it. However, a product being saleable or not is not an engineer's concern, and in organizations with well-managed job descriptions, it never is. And this applies also to small organizations, unless they are small enough that there are a handful of people managing engineering and product planning at the same time. I quite frankly don't think this is the case in the OP's question.
